# XSLT Logic for each

Tags: xslt

Below is the input. In the Loop-1,2,3 elements are unbounded. If we use for each loop  in the transformation we will get output as like A A,B B,C C. But I want the output to be same like as input.

Please see below output.

input:

```
<LOOP-1><!-- unbounded -->
<element1>A</element1>
<LOOP-1>


<LOOP-2><!-- unbounded -->
<element2>B</element2>
<LOOP-2>


<LOOP-3><!-- unbounded -->
<element3>C</element3>
<LOOP-3>



<LOOP-1>
<element1> A</element1>
<LOOP-1>


<LOOP-2>
<element2>B</element2>
<LOOP-2>


<LOOP-3>
<element3>C</element3>
<LOOP-3>
```

for the above input if we put for each we will get the out put as like

```
A
A
B
B
C
C
```

but i want the below output.how we can achieve this.the solution should be generic.appreciate your help.

output

```
<LOOP-1>
<element1>A</element1>
<LOOP-1>


<LOOP-2>
<element2>B</element2>
<LOOP-2>


<LOOP-3>
<element3>C</element3>
<LOOP-3>



<LOOP-1>
<element1> A</element1>
<LOOP-1>


<LOOP-2>
<element2>B</element2>
<LOOP-2>


<LOOP-3>
<element3>C</element3>
<LOOP-3>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LOOP-1">
  <xsl:element1>
    <xsl:value-of select="element1"/>
  </xsl:element1>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="LOOP-2">
  <xsl:element2>
    <xsl:value-of select="element2"/>
  </xsl:element2>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="LOOP-3">
  <xsl:element3>
    <xsl:value-of select="element3"/>
  </xsl:element3>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What do you mean "if we put for each". What does your XSLT look like? Your desired output appears to be identical to your input. If that's the case, then why are you using an XSLT at all?

Comment: I think the question is, for input AABBCC, output ABCABC.  I assume for input ABBBCC then output should be ABCBCB.

Comment: MY xslt is looks like above i have added.I am using this in oracles xslt transformation.

Comment: @mikey the input is A B C A B C.i want the output also like same.

Comment: If you want the exact same output, use `xsl:copy` or `xsl:copy-of`.

Comment: What is the objective of this XSLT? What do you want to do? If you want an exact copy of your XML, then as I already asked, why use XSLT at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:for-each>` is not necessary, and makes things more complicated and difficult in this instance.

**If you simply want to produce an exact copy of the source XML in your output, then you can use `<xsl:copy-of>`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Another option is to use an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The advantage of the identity transform is that if/when you do want to customize the output and transform any of the content, you can simply add a template to match that node or attribute to handle that special case.

For instance, if you wanted to produce different output for the second `B`, you could add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="LOOP-2[2]/element2[.='B']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>This is a special case for the second LOOP-2/element2 who's text() equals 'B'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```